# Calabash -Android: Can we simulate Home button on Android devices for Calabash-Android?

Tags: android, ruby, android-emulator, device, calabash

Can we simulate Home button on Android devices for Calabash-Android? I need to tap on Home button in our scripts to execute my Scripts using Calabash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried this yet myself.
But looking around for a solution I did find this.

Link http://krazyrobot.com/2014/02/calabash-android-enter-text-from-keyboard-using-adb/
by Balazs Balazs aka [krazyrobot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/626628/krazyrobot)

His solution is to use send keycodes, for the home button that is KEYCODE_HOME.
Wrapping that into calabash would give you:

`system("adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_HOME")`

Again I have not tried this, but it sounds like a solution.

Comment: Thx for the link :)
I wrote the blog post and yes, the command above is working. Note: this will fail if you have two devices connected.

Once my pull request is merged you can use the keyboard_enter_keyevent('KEYCODE_HOME') command - which supports multiple devices.

Comment: @Lasse Thnx for your reply. i just added input to ur script and that worked well.system("adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_HOME") Krazyrobot: Good information in your blog and waiting for command which supports multiple devices

Comment: Ha, @RajChinta, good spot with the input. I made an edit. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, the

```
system("adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_BACK")
```

works if you just want to go back a screen.