# Calabash - Send app to background and come back (Android)

Tags: android, calabash, calabash-android

I'm testing my android app with Calabash and everything is fine except for a small detail. I override onPause() and onResume() method to perform certain actions and I would like to test them. The problem is I'm not sure about how to do it with calabash.

I read we can send the app to the background executing

```
system("adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_HOME")
```

Ref: ([Calabash -Android: Can we simulate Home button on Android devices for Calabash-Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609126/calabash-android-can-we-simulate-home-button-on-android-devices-for-calabash-a))

That is ok for test onPause() method but I also need to test onResume()and for that I need to come back into the app. Is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: You can call onResume() method from another method, which can be execute successfully.

Comment: It is not so simple like force onResume method execution, I really need to send the app into background.

Comment: @BSavaliya you should NEVER call any of the lifecycle methods yourself. The code in the method will be called, but there will be no state transition within the activity. This is really bad advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll admit I have no experience with Calabash, but since it seems you have access to adb, you could use the "am" command within adb to launch an activity:

```
adb shell am start -n com.somepackagename/com.somepackagename.SomeActivityName
```

Just enter your app's package and activity class name here and it will emulate you starting the app from the launcher.

Note however that depending on the [launch mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)  (singleTop etc) of your activity this could however either result in a new instance of your activity being launched, or the one running in the background being resumed.

Comment: I'm not using that solution because for me is not 100% valid (I've got several activities and I need to resume the same which was closed), but that comment help me to find the solution. I'm using "adb shell monkey -p <package> 1". Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Technically not supported... below this I have my workaround that seems to work.

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/calabash-android/0.5.8/Calabash/Android/Operations:app_to_background

Not implemented yet

```
def app_to_background(secs)
  ni
end
```

In my feature file:

```
@automated @high @test
Scenario Outline: Login with keep me signed in background and relaunch
  Given I am on the Login page
  When I check keep me signed in 
  When I log into Overview page with "<acct>"
  When I background the app
  When I relaunch the app 
  Then I am on the Overview page
```

My step definitions to background and relaunch:

```
When /I background the app/ do
  `adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_HOME`
  sleep(5)
end

When  /I relaunch the app/ do
  attempts = 0
  begin
    attempts = attempts + 1
    start_test_server_in_background
  rescue RuntimeError => e 
    retry if attempts < 3
  end  
    sleep(5)
end
```

start_test_server_in_background (above) takes me right back into the app and not the Login screen. You notice in my steps that I have `When I check keep me signed in`. I don't know how reliable this all is but it works for the application that I am testing.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this the following way - ignore the ipad and iphone steps if they don't apply to you.

```
Then(/^I deactivate app for (\d+) seconds$/) do |arg1|
  if $device == "ipad" || $device == "iphone"
    send_uia_command(:command => "target.deactivateAppForDuration(5)")
  elsif $device == "androidtablet" || $device == "androidphone"
    system("#{default_device.adb_command} shell input keyevent KEYCODE_HOME")
    sleep(5)
    system("#{default_device.adb_command} shell am start -n com.somepackagename/com.somepackagename.SomeActivityName")
    sleep(2)
  end
end
```